# rare bug, cant do same width div with css and html, is it my computer?

Tags: html, css

im currently makeing some form

you can see at http://jsfiddle.net/AnMSa/

it is working fine

[image]

but when i run it on my localhost.. it turns like

[image]

ive countered this bug till yesterday, and now its time to me to look for help.

heres the html if anybody wants to download it http://www.mediafire.com/?vzi7kjgcdzldh48

please tell me everything that can reproduce this kinda bug.

Comment: i have cleared my cache, everything, but nothing seems to help. its the same on chrome and firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The html file isn't valid html. it doesn't include the html or body tags or the doctype.

It works fine if you add your content in the following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
    <!-- add content here -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Or you can use the html5 boilerplate code from http://html5boilerplate.com/

Answer (score 0):

You have to determinate your Doctype.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!--- content -->
</body>
</html>
```

Do it and it will be fixed. You see it ok onjsfiddle because they have already defined the Doctype.